# Detecting Key Presses Across Applications in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, user32

This is a post that can be found on Powershell.com via Wayback machine. It is from 2015 and is not on the site anymore.
A link to it is here: [Detecting Key Presses Across Applications](https://web.archive.org/web/20151212182019/http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2015/12/08/detecting-key-presses-across-applications.aspx).

This post is meant to be Archival.

Answer (score 3):

> By accessing the Windows low-level system calls, PowerShell can query
>   the keyboard for pressed keys. The following example waits until the
>   user presses 'A'. This is a simple example that does not consider the
>   state of the SHIFT keys, nor does it check virtual keys. However, it
>   detects key presses across all open applications. So PowerShell will
>   detect a pressed "A" key even if it does not have focus, and you
>   entered "A" into a different application.

```
#requires -Version 2

$signature = @'
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling=true)] 
public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int virtualKeyCode); 
'@

# load signatures and make members available
$API = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Name 'Keypress' -Namespace API -PassThru

# wait for 'A'
$waitFor = 'A'
$ascii = [byte][char]$waitFor.ToUpper()

do 
{
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 40
} until ($API::GetAsyncKeyState($ascii) -eq -32767)
```